# how to fix flutter pub get permission error

Tags: flutter, dart-pub

When I try to do pub get I get an error of file permissions.

I am working with an intel mac book core I5.

Running "flutter pub get" in shopXo

> Resolving dependencies...   archive 3.3.6 (3.3.7 available)   async
> 2.10.0 (2.11.0 available)   characters 1.2.1 (1.3.0 available)   cloudinary_public 0.13.0 (0.21.0 available)   collection 1.17.0
> (1.17.1 available)   dio 5.0.3 (5.1.1 available)
> flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle 2.0.9 (2.0.13 available)
> flutter_spinkit 5.1.0 (5.2.0 available)   flutter_styled_toast 1.3.0
> (2.1.3 available)   google_fonts 4.0.3 (4.0.4 available)   http 0.13.5
> (0.13.6 available)   image 3.3.0 (4.0.16 available)   image_picker
> 0.8.7 (0.8.7+4 available)   image_picker_android 0.8.6+6 (0.8.6+11 available)   image_picker_ios 0.8.7+1 (0.8.7+3 available)   intl
> 0.18.0 (0.18.1 available)   js 0.6.5 (0.6.7 available)   lints 2.0.1 (2.1.0 available)   loader_overlay 2.1.0 (2.2.0 available)
> local_auth_android 1.0.21 (1.0.27 available)   local_auth_windows
> 1.0.7 (1.0.8 available)   matcher 0.12.13 (0.12.15 available)   material_color_utilities 0.2.0 (0.3.0 available)   meta 1.8.0 (1.9.1
> available)   path 1.8.2 (1.8.3 available)   path_provider 2.0.12
> (2.0.14 available)   path_provider_android 2.0.22 (2.0.27 available)
> path_provider_foundation 2.1.1 (2.2.2 available)   path_provider_linux
> 2.1.8 (2.1.10 available)   path_provider_platform_interface 2.0.5 (2.0.6 available)   path_provider_windows 2.1.3 (2.1.6 available)
> petitparser 5.1.0 (5.4.0 available)   plugin_platform_interface 2.1.3
> (2.1.4 available)   pointycastle 3.7.0 (3.7.3 available)
> shared_preferences 2.0.20 (2.1.0 available)
> shared_preferences_android 2.0.17 (2.1.4 available)
> shared_preferences_foundation 2.1.5 (2.2.1 available)
> shared_preferences_linux 2.1.5 (2.2.0 available)
> shared_preferences_platform_interface 2.1.1 (2.2.0 available)
> shared_preferences_web 2.0.6 (2.1.0 available)
> shared_preferences_windows 2.1.5 (2.2.0 available)   source_span 1.9.1
> (1.10.0 available)   sqflite 2.2.4+1 (2.2.8 available)
> sqflite_common 2.4.2+2 (2.4.5 available)   synchronized 3.0.1 (3.1.0
> available)   test_api 0.4.16 (0.5.2 available)   universal_io 2.0.4
> (2.2.0 available)   win32 3.1.3 (4.1.3 available)   xml 6.2.2 (6.3.0
> available) Got dependencies! Cannot open file, path =
> '.dart_tool/package_config.json' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno =
> 13) pub get failed command:
> "/Users/helppoafricalimited/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart
> __deprecated_pub --directory . get --example" pub env: {   "FLUTTER_ROOT": "/Users/helppoafricalimited/flutter",
> "PUB_ENVIRONMENT": "vscode.dart-code:flutter_cli:get",   "PUB_CACHE":
> "/Users/helppoafricalimited/.pub-cache", } exit code: 66
>
> exit code 66

Answer (score 0):

try running

```
flutter clean
```

and then

```
flutter pub get
```

in VsCode Terminal

Comment: this  give same permission error 

Deleting .dart_tool...                                               3ms
Flutter failed to delete a directory at "/Users/helppoafricalimited/Documents/shopXo/.dart_tool".
Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user.

Comment: this maybe problem of guest account or limited account try with administration privilegded account.